# permission denied, checkComponentPermissions ... requires null when Add SampleSyncAdapter to AccountManager

Tags: android, synchronization, accountmanager

When I proceed to add SampleSyncAdapter on my Droid phone I get

```
05-31 11:07:28.984: W/ActivityManager(252): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() reqUid=10120
05-31 11:07:28.984: W/ActivityManager(252): Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.example.android.samplesync/.authenticator.AuthenticatorActivity (has extras) } from  
ProcessRecord{40af7940 2341:com.motorola.blur.setup/10027} (pid=2341, uid=10027) requires null
```

The same function works ok on LG phone and emulator.

Thanks to this link http://en.it-usenet.org/thread/12875/19270/ I concluded that the AuthenticationActivity has to have

```
android:exported = "true".
```

After adding this line my Droid displayed activity upon pressing Add in Accounts and Sync. How is it that this line is not needed in LG 4.03?